# If I believe something, it becomes true- how do I convince myself I'm stealthy?

Tags: magic, super-powers, fantasy-races, belief

This is my first question on Worldbuilding, so hopefully I can get the format and so on correct.

In my world, some characters can "will" what they believe to be true into being. If they believe something with just as much certainty as the sky is blue, then they can unconsciously manifest it to be true. They cannot order things into being, **but they can be deceived by objects and tools into willing something into reality.**

A great example of what I mean is if I declare I can sneak around silently without believing it, I won't be sneaking all that silently. However, if I pick up some ear muffs and **I can't hear myself, I believe I can't be heard, then others won't hear me either.** For argument's sake, let's say I'm not too bright (don't take a mile here).

This could be achieved through ear muffs or such- the condition is **I have to absolutely believe something in order to make it true.** I can't just say "hippity hoppet I want a red rocket" to get a Ferrari in my garage- I have to absolutely believe it's already there to make it so. Say I find the keys to a Ferrari in my hallway, I could believe it's in the garage before I actually go look. Thus, I would will it into existance because the keys are in my house (again, *some* leeway with intelligence).

So, here's my question:

**With early 20th Century technology and magic allowed, what equipment/weapons/trinkets could I have that could convince me I'm a master of stealth?**

Comment: Seems like Wile E. Coyote...but with the power to catch the Road Runner. One imagines a similar level of slapstick would apply, so go for the Acme Products: Rocket-powered roller skates, bat-man costume, giant rubber band, painted-tunnel-on-wall, etc.

Comment: haha! yes he's very similar. I'm struggling with some amount of slapstick and sneaky combined. slapstick. The batman costume would be hilarious though

Comment: @user535733 also seems like the Orks from WH40k - putting on a camouflage, *any* camouflage makes them almost invisible because they are passive reality warpers. They also think that painting things red makes them move faster, so their red vehicles are better than others, even if that makes no sense.

Comment: This reminds me of Krod the Half-Orc Rogue: https://imgur.com/gallery/tKjBWlD. It's different enough that I'm not sure I could build an answer around it, but maybe you'll find inspiration there.

Comment: @user535733 You beat me to this punchline. YOUZ AZ NEVER SEEN A PURPLE ORK, RIGHT? SO DERFORE PURPLE IS DA SNEAKEIST COLOUR YA ZOGGING GIT!

Comment: At any rate, this seems story-based - what a *particular character* believes is not really world building. And it's hard to generalise "what people who have reality warping powers will believe is stealthy" - Orks are one example, but aren't the be al and end all.

Comment: To be honest I just don't understand the question.  You ask for what equipment, but it's right after you say what equipment they have.  I don't want to VTC without understanding what you are looking for.

Comment: "belief super power" needs a lot a lot of clarifications. "I believe that the twig that I picked is actually a sword, and the sword that you wielding is actually a twig" "I believe that I am a great swordfighter, and you are not" "I believe that you are actually just a figment of my imagination".